# Last/most recent month of posts

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have a staff newsletter, where a monthly issue is published just before the month it refers to.

I need my index page to display the posts for the most recent month of posts.

For example:
The current month is July, but the last month where anything was posted was May, so the index page should display Mays posts, until the next set of posts are published.

I was using:

```
$current_month = date('m');
$current_year = date('Y');
query_posts("year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&order=DESC")
```

But this would only show posts for the current month, so the index page is now blank, due to there being no posts for the current month.

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this query to display most recent last month post:

```
<?php 
$today = getdate();
$args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'year'=>$today["year"],
      'monthnum'=>$today["mon"]-1,
      'order'=>'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' =>10
);

query_posts($args);
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <H1><?php echo the_title(); ?></H1>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it looks a thought this only shows the posts based on the this month-1. I need to show posts based the last month that an item wast posted, regardless of how long ago that was. Not last month as in the month just gone. Thanks

Comment: I did think about get_lastpostdate. But I'm not sure how to get the month from that function, the codex isn;t very helpful on this function, or it's a limited function

Comment: Thanks for your help - I found the fix, your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
$lastpost = strtotime(get_lastpostdate());
$lastmonth = date('m', $lastpost);
$lastyear = date('Y', $lastpost);

$args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'year'=>$lastyear,
      'monthnum'=>$lastmonth,
      'order'=>'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' =>10
);

query_posts($args);
```

I converted the get_lastpostdate() to a timestamp and the got the year and month from that timestamp